# Restrict anonymous deletion of document in couchdb

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I am having a CouchDB and any anonymous user without even being signed in can delete the document. How do I tackle this such that only the document created by a particular user can delete it. I am using CouchApp

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it.

Follow the steps below.

1) Login as admin into couch db 
2) Click on "Configuration"
3) look for "require_valid_user" and make it true

Done...